# set up action mailer to work with rabbitmq in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabbitmq, actionmailer

i'm trying to set up actionmailer to work with rabbitmq.

in `development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.queue = Messaging::AmqpClient.instance
```

and in the the mailer:

```
class OrdersNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "me <noreply@e.me.com>"
  def queue
    Messaging::AmqpClient.instance.publish('ddd', 'test_msg')
  end
```

to send a mail I am using:

```
 OrdersNotifier.new_order_email_to_seller(self).deliver
```

bu I get :

```
undefined method `queue=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class
```

when trying to deliver the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but "queue" is a rails 4 only feature that is by now removed from master branch.

See here:

http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/asynchronous-action-mailer-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

```
The queue feature has been removed from the master branch, which means it will not be making the initial Rails 4.0 release.
```